# Optimize loop: Create a new DataFrame based on by condition

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, python-itertools

Can you optimize the following loop?

`signals = pd.DataFrame({'signal':[0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0]})`

`data = pd.DataFrame({'value':[10,11,9,5,6,4,1,4,5,5]})`

This is the loop:

```
number = []; num = 0
for index, row in signals.iterrows():
    if signals.signal[index] > 0:
        num = data.value[index]
    elif signals.signal[index] < 0:
        num = 0
    number.append(num)
```

Result is: 
`number= [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]`

Comment: Are you sure that your logic is correct? Do you really want to repeat `num` until another condition is met and then repeat that `num` and so on...

Comment: Join the two data frames and run conditional logic: `combined = signals.join(data); number = np.where(combined['signal'] > 0, combined['value'], 0).tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to optimize a loop is not to use one...but see my comment about your logic.

```
# numpy.select with your conditions
arr = np.select([signals['signal'] > 0, signals['signal'] < 0], [data['value'], 0], np.nan)
# create a dataframe and forward fill NaN then back to array
number = pd.DataFrame(arr).fillna( method='ffill').fillna(0).astype(int)[0].to_numpy().tolist()

# [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]
```